# How to compile a .sh before android project on eclipse in linux

Tags: eclipse, native-code, cocos2d-x

Im compiling a game created with lib cocos2d-x and running in eclipse + linux. If i change the native code on cpp, i have to put in the console ./build_native.sh to compile the code.

How is possible to do automatically when i run the android projecto on linux???

The problem i'm having is, if i run command ./build_native.sh, compile all the cocos2d-x library, including the non-edited files, and the process take several minutes. I will like to avoid this.

Thanks in advance

Comment: In my case it doesn't take several minutes.. If I change in a file and recompile it from build_native.sh, it does that in few seconds... not more than 10 seconds... You must be facing some other issue.

Comment: @Piperoman: are you getting code-assitence while programming in eclipse? i.e. Suppose you want to type cocos2d::CCSprite * _ship; . after writing coc and pressing Ctrl + Space are you getting code assist?

Comment: A pop-up appear pushing ctrl + space, but inside: not default proposals

Answer (score 3, accepted):

./build_native.sh clean your android assets folder and copy over all resources again at each time you run. Do you have very big resources files? if you do have and the resources are not changed often, you can modify the shell script itself to comment all those lines related to resources copying.